# Angular: Observable executes request multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-http

I am using observable in

**service**

```
getMembers(): Observable<any[]> {
return this._http.get('http://localhost/membership/main/getUsers')
  .map(response => response.json() );
}
```

**component**

```
members$: Observable<any[]>;
ngOnInit() {
 this.members$ = this._membersService.getMembers()
}
```

**requests**

```
-getUsers
-getUsers
```

both return the same JSON data

every time I load the page it returns a duplicate request. it is not about the hot and cold request. because both requests return the same response. but when I remove the observable, everything is ok. only one request

Comment: first that you need to fix is a data type of members$: any[]. Because your service when map data return data and not Observable

Comment: as I understood you are using `members$|async` in template 2 times

Comment: @Danil, wow thanks, I call the async twice because I need to add a condition if there is no value *ngIf="(members$ | async)?.length>0; else noMember, then inside the condition I loop another members$ | async that cause the duplicate request, how am I suppose to validate if not empty before I loop without duplicating request

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are using the `async` pipe at two different places in the template. To avoid the re-execution of the request, you could use the `share` operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

members$: Observable<any[]>;
// I personally prefer to set observables in ctor
constructor() {
 this.members$ = this._membersService.getMembers().share();
}
```

More info about the operator can be found [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html)

Another approach would be the use of the `async` pipe at a single place with the help of `ng-container`:

```
//template
<ng-container *ngIf="members$ | async as members">
   <span *ngIf="members.length === 0; else showMembers">No members!</span>
   <ng-template #showMembers>
     <div *ngFor="let member of members">{{member | json}}</div>
   </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I am looping the data in table row.. thats why i dont use the 2nd aporoach you said.. i dont know where to put that if condition inside table row. Maybe ill try the share function tomorrow thanks

Comment: @edizonv you would need to wrap the elements that use the 'members' value inside of a ng-container. Let me now if this helped.

Answer (score 2):

Update if you run across this in **Angular 6+**.

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
this._membersService.getMembers().pipe(share());
```

is the correct syntax now.